# Аудиовизуальный текст

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Можно ли сказать, что креолизованный текст и аудиовизуальный текст это одно и то же?

Comment: Это вопрос по русскому языку?

Answer (score 1):

Нет. Это не одно и тоже, что следует из определения. В лучшем случае аудиовизуальный - частный случай креолизованного.

Креолизованный текст — текст, фактура которого состоит из двух разнородных частей: вербальной (языковой/речевой) и невербальной (принадлежащей к другим знаковым системам, нежели естественный язык). (Вики).

Под это определение, подходит например, текст песни с нотами. Вряд ли его можно назвать аудиовизуальным.

Но повторюсь, я очень сомневаюсь, что этот вопрос тут - в "формате".

Comment: Да, вы правы... Аудио-медиальный наверное можно назвать креолизованным, а аудиовизуальный это частный случай аудио-медиального или креолизованного. Спасибо за Ваш ответ, а то запуталась.